# how can i turn date into readable english format in C

Tags: c

Converting a date format into english readable format in C eg:14/08/1994 it should print as fourteen august nineteen hundred and ninty four.I have written code for day and month for year if write in the same manner the code will becoming lengthy

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
int main()
{
    char *str,case_ch;
    int lv=0;
    str=(char *)malloc(11*sizeof(char));
    printf("enter the date in this format dd/mm/yyyy");
    scanf("%s",str);
    for(lv=0;str[lv];lv++)
    {
        if(str[lv]=='0')
        {
            switch(str[lv+1])
            {
                case '1':
                    printf("first");
                    break;
                case '2':
                    printf("second ");
                    break;
                case '3':
                    printf("third ");
                    break;
                case '4':
                    printf("fourth ");
                    break;
                case '5':
                    printf("fifth ");
                    break;
                case '6':
                    printf("sixth ");
                    break;
                case '7':
                    printf("seventh ");
                    break;
                case '8':
                    printf("eigth ");
                    break;
                case '9':
                    printf("nineth ");
                    break;
                default:
                    printf("input wrong");
                    break;
            }
            break;
        }
        else if(str[lv]=='1')
        {
            switch(str[lv+1])
            {
                case '0':
                    printf("tength ");
                    break;
                case '1':
                    printf("eleventh ");
                    break;
                case '2':
                    printf("twelevth ");
                    break;
                case '3':
                    printf("thiteenth ");
                    break;
                case '4':
                    printf("fourteenth ");
                    break;
                case '5':
                    printf("fifteenth ");
                    break;
                case '6':
                    printf("sixteenth ");
                    break;
                case '7':
                    printf("seventeenth ");
                    break;
                case '8':
                    printf("eigteenth ");
                    break;
                case '9':
                    printf("nineteenth ");
                    break;
                default:
                    printf("input wrong");
                    break;
            }
            break;
        }
        else if(str[lv]=='2')
        {
            switch(str[lv+1])
            {
                case '0':
                    printf("twenteeth ");
                    break;
                case '1':
                    printf("twenty first");
                    break;
                case '2':
                    printf("twenty second ");
                    break;
                case '3':
                    printf("twenty thrid ");
                    break;
                case '4':
                    printf("twenty fourth ");
                    break;
                case '5':
                    printf("twenty fifth ");
                    break;
                case '6':
                    printf("twenty sixth ");
                    break;
                case '7':
                    printf("twenty seventh ");
                    break;
                case '8':
                    printf("twenty eighth");
                    break;
                case '9':
                    printf("twety ningth");
                    break;
                default:
                    printf("input wrong");
                    break;
            }
            break;
        }
        else if(str[lv]=='3')
        {
            switch(str[lv+1])
            {
                case '0':
                    printf("thrity ");
                    break;
                case '1':
                    printf("thirty first");
                    break;
                default:
                    printf("invalid input");
                    break;
            }
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            printf("invalid input");
            break;
        }
    }
    for(lv=3;str[lv];lv++)
    {
        if(str[lv]=='0')
        {
            switch(str[lv+1])
            {
                case '1':
                    printf("jan");
                    break;
                case '2':
                    printf("Feb");
                    break;
                case '3':
                    printf("March ");
                    break;
                case '4':
                    printf("April");
                    break;
                case '5':
                    printf("May ");
                    break;
                case '6':
                    printf("june ");
                    break;
                case '7':
                    printf("july ");
                    break;
                case '8':
                    printf("august");
                    break;
                case '9':
                    printf("september ");
                    break;
                default:
                    printf("input wrong");
                    break;
            }
            break;
        }
        else if(str[lv]=='1')
        {
            switch(str[lv+1])
            {
                case '0':
                    printf("october");
                    break;
                case '1':
                    printf("november");
                    break;
                case '2':
                    printf("december");
                    break;
                default:
                    printf("invalid input");
                    break;
            }
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            printf("invalid input");
            break;
        }

    }
    /*how to write code for year if i write in the above manner the code will be tooo lenghty*/
}
```

Comment: If I'd been set this as homework, I'd probably start by looking at `sscanf()` to read the date-string into three `int`s.

Comment: you need to try something, and than ask for help NO ONE will write the code for you !

Comment: I tried but it is becoming too lengthy code

Comment: @user3165666 show us the code and tell us what problems are you facing in that. We might then be able to help you.

Comment: If a to call to `asctime()` wouldn't do, try `strftime()`.

Comment: None of the above two functions give the year in english format know?

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest two areas of improvement to your approach:

1. first understand the input, then produce the output
2. abstract!

Start by using `scanf` to understand your input as three numbers (`%d`).

**Side node**: the way you're handling the input string is dangerous; not only are you using `malloc` without using `free` (memory leak), you are reading arbitrarily sized input into a fixed size buffer (buffer overflow -> crashes or security holes in your software).

Now you've got three numbers in variables:

int day, month, year;

... which is a much nicer abstraction.

Next, take a minute to think about the `%` operator. `1994 % 100` is 94. `1994 / 100 % 100` is 19.

Remember how to define functions in C. You do not want to repeat yourself. So if you've defined a switch statement that handles the ordinal numbers "first", "second", and so on, you do not want a separate switch statement that handles "twenty first", "twenty second", etc. The numbers 11-19 are a special case in English, but 21st-29th work exactly the same way as 41st-49th.

So you need something along the lines of

```
void printOrdinalNumber(int n)
{
    if(n < 20)
    {
        switch(n)
        {
           ...
        }
    }
    else
    {
        int tens = n / 10;
        int ones = n % 10;

        switch(tens)
        { ... }

        if(ones >= 1)
             printOrdinalNumber(ones);
    }
}
```

You'll need to do the same for cardinal numbers, and you need to handle the special cases for years. Make sure that if "1994" is "nineteen ninety four", "2001" doesn't come out as "twenty one". And if "1994" is "nineteen hundred ninety four", "2010" still isn't "twenty hundred ten", either.

Comment: Thanks alot,i had taken the input as string because the my homework question was like that.Now i will first convert the string as number then i will proceed with your approach

Comment: so if you like my answer, don't forget to officially accept it.